# Postgres will not come up after pg_rewind

Tags: postgresql

I'm have postgres 9.6

In my code I use pg_rewind to sync the old master with the new master after failover. Although pg_rewind returns no error, I'm unable to being postgres up on the old master machine.  Below please find the log file.

Your insight is most welcome.
Avi

```
    < 2017-09-24 15:27:59.364 GMT 28163 >LOG:  database system was interrupted while in recovery at log time 2017-09-24 14:27:42 GMT
    < 2017-09-24 15:27:59.364 GMT 28163 >HINT:  If this has occurred more than once some data might be corrupted and you might need to choose an earlier recovery target.
    < 2017-09-24 15:27:59.519 GMT 28163 >LOG:  entering standby mode
    < 2017-09-24 15:27:59.519 GMT 28163 >LOG:  unexpected pageaddr 1/CC000000 in log segment 000000400000000200000012, offset 0
    < 2017-09-24 15:27:59.528 GMT 28165 >LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 2/12000000 on timeline 64
    < 2017-09-24 15:27:59.530 GMT 28163 >LOG:  unexpected pageaddr 1/CC000000 in log segment 000000400000000200000012, offset 0
    < 2017-09-24 15:27:59.530 GMT 28165 >FATAL:  terminating walreceiver process due to administrator command
    < 2017-09-24 15:27:59.531 GMT 28163 >LOG:  unexpected pageaddr 1/CC000000 in log segment 000000400000000200000012, offset 0
    < 2017-09-24 15:27:59.531 GMT 28163 >LOG:  unexpected pageaddr 1/CC000000 in log segment 000000400000000200000012, offset 0
    < 2017-09-24 15:28:04.536 GMT 28163 >LOG:  unexpected pageaddr 1/CC000000 in log segment 000000400000000200000012, offset 0
    < 2017-09-24 15:28:09.541 GMT 28163 >LOG:  unexpected pageaddr 1/CC000000 in log segment 000000400000000200000012, offset 0
    < 2017-09-24 15:28:12.863 GMT 28224 >FATAL:  the database system is starting up
    < 2017-09-24 15:28:12.872 GMT 28225 >FATAL:  the database system is starting up

some lines removed from here...

in log segment 000000400000000200000012, offset 0
    < 2017-09-24 15:32:34.812 GMT 28163 >LOG:  unexpected pageaddr 1/CC000000 in log segment 000000400000000200000012, offset 0
    < 2017-09-24 15:32:39.818 GMT 28163 >LOG:  unexpected pageaddr 1/CC000000 in log segment 000000400000000200000012, offset 0
    < 2017-09-24 15:32:44.823 GMT 28163 >LOG:  unexpected pageaddr 1/CC000000 in log segment 000000400000000200000012, offset 0
    < 2017-09-24 15:32:49.828 GMT 28163 >LOG:  unexpected pageaddr 1/CC000000 in log segment 000000400000000200000012, offset 0
    < 2017-09-24 15:32:51.686 GMT 29118 >FATAL:  the database system is starting up
    < 2017-09-24 15:32:51.830 GMT 29119 >FATAL:  the database system is starting up
    < 2017-09-24 15:32:54.833 GMT 28163 >LOG:  unexpected pageaddr 1/CC000000 in log segment 000000400000000200000012, offset 0
    < 2017-09-24 15:32:59.234 GMT 28155 >LOG:  received fast shutdown request
    < 2017-09-24 15:32:59.237 GMT 29143 >LOG:  shutting down
    < 2017-09-24 15:32:59.350 GMT 28155 >LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded from version 9.6.3 to 9.6.5 and the problem seems to disappear.  I checked the release notes for versions 9.6.4 and 9.6.5 and there was a pg_rewind fix for problem in files over 2GB in size, however my files are smaller than that so I do not know if it related to this fix or not.